# Reflecting an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, reflection

I am new in Java and have a task to write some application. Faced one problem which can not pass :(

The issue is to update an array element through reflection (app selecting public array to update dinamicaly depending on string app reading from file):

First, i have reflected boolean variables as follows:

```
activity = activityName(activities[i].substring(0,activities[i].lastIndexOf('.', activities[i].length() - 4)));  
Field field = refClass.getField(activity);  
Object obj = field;  
field.setBoolean(obj, true);
```

And that worked for me well. But now i need to use arrays instead of regular variables, and tried to make as follows:

```
activity = activityName(activities[i].substring(0, activities[i].lastIndexOf('.',  activities[i].length() - 4)));  
Field field = refClass.getField(activity);  
Object field_act = field;  
field_act.setBoolean(field_act, LMKStorage.currentLmkSlot, true);
```

And getting exception "Argument not an array". :(

In `field_act.setBoolean(field_act, LMKStorage.currentLmkSlot, true);`, `field_act` is boolean[] i am getting with `.getField(activity)`, `LMKStorage.currentLmkSlot` is int to determine which position of an array to set and "true" is value to set. The field_act i have to get 100% is an array, because i have not non-array static variables in refClass.

so far i have got studing books i have.But still nothing. Tried to google any examples to update array elements... nothing usefull for me.

Please advice.

Comment: why are you using the `field_act` variable instead of `field`? `Object` doesn't have a `setBoolean` method. Can you post your actual code?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your working example. Your obj variable is the field representation object? obj should be some instance of your refClass.

Comment: Actually, i tried many ways, and `field` was too.                   `activity = activityName(activities[i].substring(0, activities[i].lastIndexOf('.', activities[i].length() - 4)));  
Field field = refClass.getField(activity);  
Object field_act = field;    
Array.setBoolean(field, LMKStorage.currentLmkSlot, true);  Just tried to use `field` which is `Field` type and got:  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument is not an array

Comment: Can't you just retrieve the array with `Field.get`, cast it to a `boolean[]`, and set the value in that?

Comment: Sorry, for mistakes in formating posts, i am first time here and experimenting to get my posts nice.

Answer (score 1):

For arrays, use [`java.lang.reflect.Array`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html) instead of `java.lang.reflect.Field`.

```
Object field_act = field.get(obj);
Array.setBoolean(field_act, LMKStorage.currentLmkSlot, true);
```

Comment: Yess, You are correct that was my mistake while asking question. The correct code is:      Array.setBoolean(field_act, LMKStorage.currentLmkSlot, true);

Comment: Then the mistake is in your code. You should replace `Object field_act = field;` with the line `Object field_act = field.get(obj);`.